# you must specify an existing container or a new image when specifying args

Tags: kubernetes

According to [the Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#debug), you can start a debug version of a container and run a command on it like this:

```sh
$ kubectl debug (POD | TYPE[[.VERSION].GROUP]/NAME) [ -- COMMAND [args...] ]
```

But when I try and do this in real life I get the following:

```sh
$ kubectl debug mypod \
  --copy-to=mypod-dev \
  --env='PYTHONPATH="/my_app"' \
  --set-image=mycontainer=myimage:dev -- python do_the_debugging.py
error: you must specify an existing container or a new image when specifying args.
```

If I don't specify `-- python do_the_debugging.py` I can create the debug container, but then I need a separate command to actually do the debugging:

```sh
kubectl exec -it mypod-dev -- python do_the_debugging.py
```

Why can't I do this all in one line as the docs seem to specify?

---

Some kubernetes details:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.1", GitCommit:"c4d752765b3bbac2237bf87cf0b1c2e307844666", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-23T02:22:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16+", GitVersion:"v1.16.15-eks-ad4801", GitCommit:"ad4801fd44fe0f125c8d13f1b1d4827e8884476d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-10-20T23:27:12Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: `kubectl debug` is still beta, it could be buggy (no pun intended). Also your server and client versions are pretty out of sync, I don't know if there could be an issue there or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `-it` and `--container` flags to your command. In your specific case, it might look like this:

```
$ kubectl debug mypod \
  --copy-to=mypod-dev \
  --env='PYTHONPATH="/my_app"' \
  --set-image=mycontainer=myimage:dev \
  --container=mycontainer -it -- python do_the_debugging.py
```

I am not able to reproduce your exact issue because I don't have the `do_the_debugging.py` script, but I've created simple example.
First, I created `Pod` with name `web` using `nginx` image:

```
root@kmaster:~# kubectl run web --image=nginx
pod/web created
```

And then I ran `kubectl debug` command to create a copy of `web` named `web-test-1` but with `httpd` image:

```
root@kmaster:~# kubectl debug web --copy-to=web-test-1 --set-image=web=httpd --container=web -it -- bash
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
root@web-test-1:/usr/local/apache2#
```

Furthermore, I recommend you to upgrade your cluster to a newer version because your client and server versions are very diffrent.
Your `kubectl` version is `1.20`, therefore you should have `kube-apiserver` in version `1.19` or `1.20`.
Generally speaking if `kube-apiserver` is in version `X`, `kubectl` should be in version `X-1` or `X` or `X+1`.

Comment: Yep, adding the container name and `-it` worked. Actually once I see this, the original error message _did_ make sense. I just didn't get it!